# using block scopes to organize complex code

Tags: javascript, scope, comments, documentation

I am building a three.js library and found placing comments and nesting content below the comment in {} made it easy to navigate lots of code. I  was wondering if there are other better ways to do this.

**Why I would like to do this**

1. the main reason: **I can quickly collapse code based on the comments I see above the block scopes**. Thereby **making it easy to focus on the code I want to change.**
2. I'd only use this in the class initialisation, or very complex methods. Or rather, any areas where there is significant code use with applicable labels for those areas.
3. I would never scope a section without an appropriate comment accompanying it.
4. This helps me scale these different sections, especially if they are not something that would scale into a new class or object within reason
5. Im aware a common problem with code bases is they can be extremely overwhelming, especially when learning them. I think this way of organising code could help make it more approachable and less overwhelming to look at
6. I would love if there was a feature in IDE's to do something like this

**Example of its use:**

***Collapsed:*** 
[image]

***Un-collapsed:***

[image]

**Collapsed:**

[image]

**Un-collapsed**

[image]

I also see this as a *compliment* to refactoring, whether it's abstracting into functions or more classes. This seems to be agile and deals with uncertainty in the code base especially if you need to neatly layer problems solutions into themselves in ways that would not qualify a new class, or new method.

Comment: Are you using a module system / bundler (like Webpack)? (if not, you probably should, it *really* helps with code organization for more professional code when it isn't trivially short)

Comment: You can also extract the funcionality into separate functions/methods, so you'd have `baseWebWorkers(); handleMobile(); baseLoadingManager()` etc. Although what you have here is basically the `#region` directive from C# - it does exactly what you have here, you signify a collapsible region and you can put a comment for what it's about

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, and i'm using it with eslint. I have quite a complex webpack configuration for this project too. Classes are being imported and exported, its nice yes. But dosen't address this projects particular needs per se

Comment: The separate-functions method is what I was going to suggest too - put the code into functions in separate files, then import the functions and call them in the constructor. When you need to examine / modify a particular part of the code, go to the appropriate file.

Comment: @VLAZ very cool c# feature! Wouldn't pushing lots of things to functions get messy aswell though? Functions dont have multiple layers, and I find functions calling functions inside them get extremely confusing and frustrating to maintain.

Comment: @CertainPerformance very good point, I would often see this, and you can see similar separation of concerns into files in languages like c++ and c with header files. I think personally it gets overwhelming and messy that way and leads to more complex file system structures which can be a pain in the arse for server-side stuff or with web pack and importing modules. Would it be better to try to organise some things in the code this way?

Comment: If the alternative is 100+ lines of somewhat-unrelated code, using separate functions for the main few functionalities would be much less painful, from a maintainability perspective - a block's code folding alone doesn't cut it IMO

Comment: The functions/methods are an option. Not always the correct one but it's a [known refactoring pattern](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method). It achieves what you have here - groups some lines of code together and gives them a short description of what the grouping would do. You can then look at what you have at a different point in time. Collapsing, it's slightly easier since you can just expand the region, while if you have a function/method call you have to navigate to it. But this could be a benefit, as well, since sometimes you might prefer *not* to have all the code in the same place.

Comment: @VLAZ totally agree, and I definitely use lots of functions as well. I think this scoping idea is a beneficial COMPLIMENT to breaking things down into functions or classes. Especially if you not fully certain of the requirements/future features of the project. Making this a tad bit more agile and friendly for future refactoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's better to break down into separate functions. Adding unnecessary blocks could have surprising consequences for future maintainers. Many editors support using a special syntax within comments to aid code folding and navigation without altering the syntax tree.

[Edit]
Whilst I am really an Emacs-only guy (TM), the docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) for Vscode suggest something along the lines of

```
//#region
```

Comment: Regions are an excellent alternative that seem to be established. Thank you for sharing this, I sometimes saw them in c++ code but didn't understand the purpose until now! Cheers